# What governs switching of refresh rate in "Pro Motion" iPads?

Tags: ios, graphics, energy

A major new feature in the latest generation of iPad Pro is the automatic adaptation of screen refresh rate.

I haven't found any documentation of the level at which this is controlled, whether it is something that it is possible (or even desirable) to explicitly specify from a running app, or indeed if there might be costs associated with frequently switching, for example in cases where a high refresh rate is desired only intermittently as the user is interacting.

As of this writing, I don't have such a device to test with, and am also not sure of what information the developer tools - Energy Gauges or Time Profiler - convey about how these states switch during runtime and the resulting energy consumption, whether it is handled automatically by iOS or not.